# Problemas setteando una variable booleana

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy programando una calculadora web con javaScript y lo que quiero lograr es que por ejemplo: cuando sumo dos valores y doy click en el signo menos este ejecute primero la suma pendiente(esto lo esta haciendo bien), ahora cuando ingreso otro numero y vuelvo a ejecutar el signo menos debe calcular la resta(lo que esta pasando es que vuelve a sumar). Yo estoy tratando de controlar las funciones con variables booleanas pero veo que es como que no cambia el estado de la variable. A continuación el código. Me pueden ayudar con esto porque no veo donde esta mi error. Gracias

```
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><input id="display" name="display" disabled=""></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
  <td><button id="button1" value="1">1</button></td>
  <td><button id="button2" value="2">2</button></td>
  <td><button id="button3" value="3">3</button></td>
  <td><button id="addButton">+</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="button4" value="4">4</button></td>
  <td><button id="button5" value="5">5</button></td>
  <td><button id="button6" value="6">6</button></td>
  <td><button id="subtractButton">-</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="button7" value="7">7</button></td>
  <td><button id="button8" value="8">8</button></td>
  <td><button id="button9" value="9">9</button></td>
  <td><button id="multiplyButton">*</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="clearButton">C</button></td>
  <td><button id="button0" value="0">0</button></td>
  <td><button id="equalsButton">=</button></td>
  <td><button id="divideButton">÷</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
var nunArray = []; //arreglo que almacena los resultados
var newArray = [];
var operation = false;
var suma = false;
var restar = false;
var result = 0;
var total = 0;

//---------Funciones Auxiliares---------------------
//Convertir a entero
var convertir = function arrayANumber(array){
var num = "0";
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    num += array[i];
}
return (parseInt(num));
}
//Funcion Suma
var sumaFuncion = function suma(){
    total += convertir(newArray);
    newArray.length = 0;
    suma = false;
    $('#display').val(total);
}
var restaFuncion = function resta(){
    total -= convertir(newArray);
    newArray.length = 0;
    restar = false;
    $('#display').val(total);
}
//----------Funciones de los Operadores------------------------
// Accion restar 
$('#subtractButton').click(function(){
    operation = true;   
    restar = true;
    if(suma){//Aqui se activa la funcion suma se previamente fue invocada
        sumaFuncion();
    }else if(newArray.length) {//Aqui resta si ya fue ingresado el segundo 
numero
        restaFuncion(); 
    }else if (nunArray.length){//Aqui se presiona la resta y se muestra el 
primer valor ingresado
         total = convertir(nunArray);
         $('#display').val(total);
    }
});
   //Accion sumar    
  $('#addButton').click(function(){
    operation = true;   
    suma = true;
    if(newArray.length){//Aqui ejecuta la funcion cuando se ingresa el 
  segundo valor
        sumaFuncion();
    }else if (nunArray.length) {//Aqui ejecuta la funcion cuando se ingresa 
  el primer valor
        total += convertir(nunArray);
         nunArray.length = 0;
         $('#display').val(total);
    }else{//Aqui carga el valor total o acumulador cuando se da click por 
  segunda vez el boton
        $('#display').val(total);
    }
  });

 //---------------Programacion de Botones Numericos-----------------------
 $('#button1').click(function(){
  //probar la variable global newArray
    if (operation == true) {
         newArray.push($('#button1').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button1').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button2').click(function(){
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button2').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button2').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button3').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button3').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button3').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button4').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button4').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button4').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button5').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button5').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button5').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button6').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button6').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button6').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button7').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button7').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button7').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button8').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button8').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button8').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button9').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button9').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button9').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
  $('#button0').click(function(){   
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button0').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button0').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});

//--------------Funcion de Los botones CLEAR e IGUAL------------------------      
$('#clearButton').click(function(){ 
    nunArray.length = 0;
    newArray.length = 0;
    operation = false;
    suma = false;
    multiplicar = false;
    dividir = false;
    restar = false;
    total = 0;
    $('#display').val("0");
});     

 //Accion igualar
 $('#equalsButton').click(function(){
    if(suma){
        sumaFuncion();
    }else if(restar){
         restaFuncion();
    } else{
        $('#display').val(total);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veo bastantes problemas en el código.

Por un lado tienes una variable y una función que comparten el nombre `suma`.

Por otra lado al llevar la operación marcada en distinta variable en función de la operación seleccionada hay momentos en que se da la circunstancia de que tanto la variable `suma` como `restar` pueden estar puestas a `true`.

Lo mejor sería que llevases la operación pendiente en una única variable. En el ejemplo que te pongo la variable `operacion` puede tomar los valores 0 (`NINGUNA`), 1 (`SUMAR`) ó 2 (`RESTAR`).

Tampoco necesitas mantener dos arrays para los valores introducidos. Si es el primer valor y no hay ninguna operación seleccionada no hay más que ejecutar la operación suma por defecto sobre el valor actual que será 0.

Aquí tienes cómo podría quedarte:

```js
var newArray = [];
var NINGUNA = 0;
var SUMAR = 1;
var RESTAR = 2;
var operation = NINGUNA;
var total = 0;

//---------Funciones Auxiliares---------------------
//Convertir a entero
var convertir = function arrayANumber(array){
var num = "0";
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    num += array[i];
}
return (parseInt(num));
}
// Ejecuta la operación pendiente si
// la hay y muestra el resultado
function ejecutarOperacion(){
  // Si no hay nuevo valor no hace nada
  if (!newArray.length){
    return;
  }
  // Ejecuta la operación pendiente
  switch(operation){
    case RESTAR:
      restaFuncion();
      break;
    default:
      sumaFuncion();
  }
  // Inicializa valores y muestra resultado
  newArray.length = 0;
  operation = NINGUNA;
  $('#display').val(total);
}
//Funcion Suma
var sumaFuncion = function suma(){
    total += convertir(newArray);
}
var restaFuncion = function resta(){
    total -= convertir(newArray);
}
//----------Funciones de los Operadores------------------------
// Accion restar 
$('#subtractButton').click(function(){
  // Ejecuta operación pendiente
  ejecutarOperacion();
  // Establece RESTAR como operación pendiente
  operation = RESTAR;
});
 //Accion sumar    
$('#addButton').click(function(){
  // Ejecuta operación pendiente
  ejecutarOperacion();
  // Establece SUMAR como operación pendiente
  operation = SUMAR;
});

//---------------Programacion de Botones Numericos-----------------------
$('#button1').click(function(){
   newArray.push($('#button1').val());
  $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
});
$('#button2').click(function(){
  newArray.push($('#button2').val());
  $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
});
$('#button3').click(function(){    
  newArray.push($('#button3').val());
  $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
});
$('#button4').click(function(){    
  newArray.push($('#button4').val());
  $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
});
$('#button5').click(function(){    
  newArray.push($('#button5').val());
  $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
});
$('#button6').click(function(){    
  newArray.push($('#button6').val());
  $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
});
$('#button7').click(function(){    
  newArray.push($('#button7').val());
  $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
});
$('#button8').click(function(){    
  newArray.push($('#button8').val());
  $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
});
$('#button9').click(function(){    
  newArray.push($('#button9').val());
  $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
});
$('#button0').click(function(){   
  newArray.push($('#button0').val());
  $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
});

//--------------Funcion de Los botones CLEAR e IGUAL------------------------      
$('#clearButton').click(function(){ 
    newArray.length = 0;
    operation = NINGUNA;
    total = 0;
    $('#display').val("0");
});     

 //Accion igualar
$('#equalsButton').click(function(){
  ejecutarOperacion();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><input id="display" name="display" disabled=""></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
  <td><button id="button1" value="1">1</button></td>
  <td><button id="button2" value="2">2</button></td>
  <td><button id="button3" value="3">3</button></td>
  <td><button id="addButton">+</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="button4" value="4">4</button></td>
  <td><button id="button5" value="5">5</button></td>
  <td><button id="button6" value="6">6</button></td>
  <td><button id="subtractButton">-</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="button7" value="7">7</button></td>
  <td><button id="button8" value="8">8</button></td>
  <td><button id="button9" value="9">9</button></td>
  <td><button id="multiplyButton">*</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="clearButton">C</button></td>
  <td><button id="button0" value="0">0</button></td>
  <td><button id="equalsButton">=</button></td>
  <td><button id="divideButton">÷</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Aún podrías optimizar bastante más el código.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo que igual te sirve para practicar.

He agrupado los botones utilizando clases. A los botones de operación les he asignado una clase `operation` y le he asignado en el `value` el valor de la operación a ejecutar. De esta forma con un única función puede controlar el evento `click` de todos ellos.

De la misma forma a los números les he asignado la clase `number` (el valor ya lo tenían asignado) y así también se puede controlar la funcionalidad del `click` con una única función.

```js
var newArray = [];
var NINGUNA = 0;
var SUMAR = 1;
var RESTAR = 2;
var MULTIPLICAR = 3;
var DIVIDIR = 4;
var operation = NINGUNA;
var total = 0;

//---------Funciones Auxiliares---------------------
//Convertir a entero
function convertir(array){
  return parseInt('0' + array.join(''));
}
// Ejecuta la operación pendiente si
// la hay y muestra el resultado
function ejecutarOperacion(){
  // Si no hay nuevo valor no hace nada
  if (!newArray.length){
    return;
  }
  // Ejecuta la operación pendiente
  switch(operation){
    case RESTAR:
      total -= convertir(newArray);
      break;
    case MULTIPLICAR:
      total *= convertir(newArray);
      break;
    case DIVIDIR:
      total /= convertir(newArray);
      break;
    default:
      total += convertir(newArray);
  }
  // Inicializa valores y muestra resultado
  newArray.length = 0;
  operation = NINGUNA;
  $('#display').val(total);
}
//----------Funciones de los Operadores------------------------
$('.operation').click(function(){
  // Ejecuta operación pendiente
  ejecutarOperacion();
  // Establece operación pendiente
  operation = parseInt($(this).val());
});
//---------------Programacion de Botones Numericos-----------------------
$('.number').click(function(){
  newArray.push($(this).val());
  $('#display').val(newArray.join(''));
});

//--------------Funcion CLEAR ------------------------      
$('#clearButton').click(function(){ 
    newArray.length = 0;
    operation = NINGUNA;
    total = 0;
    $('#display').val("0");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><input id="display" name="display" disabled=""></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
  <td><button id="button1" class="number" value="1">1</button></td>
  <td><button id="button2" class="number" value="2">2</button></td>
  <td><button id="button3" class="number" value="3">3</button></td>
  <td><button id="addButton" class="operation" value="1">+</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="button4" class="number" value="4">4</button></td>
  <td><button id="button5" class="number" value="5">5</button></td>
  <td><button id="button6" class="number" value="6">6</button></td>
  <td><button id="subtractButton" class="operation" value="2">-</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="button7" class="number" value="7">7</button></td>
  <td><button id="button8" class="number" value="8">8</button></td>
  <td><button id="button9" class="number" value="9">9</button></td>
  <td><button id="multiplyButton" class="operation" value="3">*</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="clearButton">C</button></td>
  <td><button id="button0" class="number" value="0">0</button></td>
  <td><button id="equalsButton" class="operation" value="0">=</button></td>
  <td><button id="divideButton" class="operation" value="4">÷</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola Asier muchas gracias por tu reflexion. Realmente el problema estaba en que tenia las funciones con el mismo nombre de las variables booleanas globales. Cambie solo eso y funciono. Es cierto que mi codigo esta enredado jeje es que recien comienzo en este mundo de la programacion y por ejemplo mirando tu codigo que es mas limpio veo que usas switch que es una operacion que si la conocia pero todavia no la domino bien. Te reitero las gracias y me aclaraste todo. Saludos

Comment: Te he añadido un nuevo ejemplo con el código más compacto y sin repetir funcionalidad (como por ejemplo la de los botones de número). Espero que te sirva para ver otras formas de hacerlo e ir aprendiendo. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola nuevamente Asier se me ocurrio ademas de lo del cambio de nombre en las funciones agregar un if preguntando si esta activa la variable de la operacion que precede a la que se va a realizar y la setteo y ahora si funciona a mil, porque tenia el problema que en la tercera operacion no funcionaba pero ya esta. Mil gracias